# Function to reverse a linked list recursively

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, linked-list, nodes

I was trying to write this function to reverse singly linked list and I'm unable to find what has gone wrong here.

```
void reverse(node *&c, node *&p){
    if(c = NULL){
        c = p;
        return;
    }
    node *n = c->next;
    c->next = p;
    p = c;
    c = n;
    reverse(c, p);
}
```

c = current node, p = previous node, n = next node.

I found multiple solutions on the internet having return type 'node*' and some others too but I want to find what's going wrong with my implementation

Comment: `if(c = NULL)`? You mean `if(c == NULL)`? Doesn't your compiler warn you here?

Comment: @Blaze use the compiler flag `-wall`. it may point you to this then.

Comment: Can you share some sample data, and the expected output?

Comment: I'm curious how this should be called in the first place.

Comment: Yes. The mistake that I put the assignment operator instead of comparison operator really had me thinking of my logic. BTW, I use DevC++ for coding and it didn't warn me of anything.

Comment: @sparrow DevC++ is outdated and unmaintained. Use VisualStudio or CodeBlocks or any of the other actually good IDEs

Comment: Switching to CodeBlocks.

Comment: @sparrow CodeLite or Eclipse are also valid options, though afaik eclipse is mainly used for java. Here is a list I found with a quick search: https://www.tecmint.com/best-linux-ide-editors-source-code-editors/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an assignment in your condition `if(c = NULL)`. This is valid c/c++, and will assign NULL to c. The result of the assignment (NULL) is then used as the condition in your if-statement, which will then always evaluate false.

Replace the assignment with a comparison for equality (`==`)

Using side effects in your conditions is bad practice and should be avoided. It can cause hard to find bugs. Even if an assignent is what you want, you should use it before the if statement and then check the variable.
Other bad side effects may be such things as `if (someExpression && (a++ == 5))`, where a may or may not be incremented depending on compiler settings.

Comment: All this time I was thinking if my logic was incorrect. But this is a silly but a big mistake :'( Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @sparrow is the rest of your logic correct?

Comment: yes it is correct. @falcoger

Answer (score 1):

In your if statement, you are assigning NULL to c. Replace "=" with "==". I like to change the ordwrite something like if(NULL == variable)because if I miss one "=", I will get an error.